# Reproducing results from Ordistep

Tags: r, random-seed, vegan, rda

Relatively new to R and first time posting so my apologies if there is something missing in my question.
I'm using Vegan's [ordistep](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/vegan/docs/ordistep) function for variable selection using the default "both" direction method. 
I'm using a Hellinger transformed Species Abundance data frame as response variables and a 12 column independent variables data frame. 
I seem to get different inclusion variables if I run the same code (below) multiple times. I'm assuming there is a pseudo number generator involved that set.seed can't constrain. Is there a way to reproduce consistent results?

```
set.seed(2000)
step.both <- ordistep(pre_met.rda, pstep=1000)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ordistep` uses standard R RNG and honours `set.seed()`. I can't reproduce your problem, but I get exactly the same results when I set seed to the same value before call.

Current version of `ordistep` has no `pstep` argument. Although we now have a new implementation, we have always honoured R `set.seed()`.

Comment: Thank you Dr. Oksanen. I believe my error was that I assumed setting the seed at the beginning of the script would remain the same for the duration of the session. The issue above only happened when I ran only the ordistep line repeatedly. Once I started setting the seed each time I ran ordistep the results came back the same. Thanks again!